# How to change HttpClient code after update app to Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-httpclient

I updated Angular to version 7 into my app and I have to change my code a little bit after update but I'm not sure how to do it.

This is example of code to change (in previous version of Angular):

```
get(): Observable<MyResponseClass | null> {
    let url_ = some_url;

    let options_: any = {
        method: "get",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        })
    };

    return this.http.request(url_, options_).flatMap((response_: any) => {
        return this.getResponse(response_);
    }).catch((response_: any) => {
        if (response_ instanceof Response) {
            try {
                return this.getResponse(<any>response_);
            } catch (e) {
                return <Observable<MyResponseClass | null>><any>Observable.throw(e);
            }
        } else
            return <Observable<MyResponseClass | null>><any>Observable.throw(response_);
    });
}
```

For this question it doesn't matter what `getResponse` and `MyResponseClass` they are, so I'll skip to explain that.

Ok, so the first step is changing .flatMap to .pipe() and map() because of that:

> Property 'flatMap' does not exist on type Observable<Object>.

So after this change my code looks like that:

```
return this.http.request(url_, options_).pipe(map((response_: any) => { 
            return this.getResponse(response_); })
        ).catch((response_: any) => {
            if (response_ instanceof Response) {
                try {
                    return this.getResponse(<any>response_);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<MyResponseClass | null>><any>Observable.throw(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<MyResponseClass | null>><any>Observable.throw(response_);
        });
```

And now I've got the error like that:

> Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Observable<MyResponseClass>>'.

And here I've got the problem because I really don't know what I should to change it. I'm still looking for some information into google and stack overflow but without success yet. Maybe I haven't enough knowladge of that.

Will you help me with that?

Comment: can you `return e;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `RxJS` is most probably updated from v5.x to v6.x. Therefore you need to refactor your code which involves `RxJS`.

Here is the update guide:

[https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax)

Comment: That's what I'm saying. You probably had the previous `RxJS` version (v5.x) before update. And after you updated, it is throwing errors because the function definitions and namings are changed. For example, `catch` becomes `catchError`.

Comment: Here is a continuation of my bug if you still want to help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441514/error-after-update-app-to-angular-7-and-rxjs-6-3-3

Comment: I will certainly have a look at when I have time.

Comment: thank you a lot ! I'll be still looking for solution of that.

Answer (score 2):

Aa per [rxjs V6 Update Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) `chaining operators has been replaced by piping` also `catch` changed to `catchError` so your final code should be

```
  return this.http.request(url_, options_).pipe(map((response_: any) => { 
                return this.getResponse(response_); }),
              catchError((response_: any) => {
                if (response_ instanceof Response) {
                    try {
                        return this.getResponse(<any>response_);
                    } catch (e) {
                        return <Observable<MyResponseClass | null>><any>Observable.throw(e);
                    }
                } else
                    return <Observable<MyResponseClass | null>><any>Observable.throw(response_);
            })
            );
```

Or you can use [rxjs-compact](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat)

Comment: I updated my question and I put a error into question content after this change. I think that it is not a end of change.

Comment: @Presto This is not related to the one you ask.you might get more error after this as well those can't be answered in the same thread

Comment: You're right. I rollback a question to previous form

Comment: Here is a continuation of my bug if you still want to help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441514/error-after-update-app-to-angular-7-and-rxjs-6-3-3