# Problem with Observable after update app to Angular 7 and RxJS 6.3.3

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, angular-httpclient, rxjs6

I updated my app to Angular 7 and RxJS 6.3.3 and I've got a problems during making changes into my code. I really need help with that, because I can't to find solution into google or stack overflow.

My imports:

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, ResponseContentType, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Here is code of my `test` function:

```
protected test(response: Response): Observable<MyResponseClass | null> {
    const status = response.status;

    if (status === 200) {
       let result200: any = null;
       ... some code ...
       return of<MyResponseClass | null>(result200);
    }
    return of<MyResponseClass | null>(<any>null);
}
```

Here is `MyResponseClass` pseudocode:

```
class MyResponseClass implements IMyResponseClass {
    property1?: string | undefined;
    property2?: string | undefined;
    property3: boolean;

    ...
}
```

`IMyResponseClass` pseudocode:

```
interface IMyResponseClass {
    property1?: string | undefined;
    property2?: string | undefined;
    property3: boolean;
}
```

Here is my code of my `get()` function:

```
get(): Observable<MyResponseClass | null> {
    let url_ = some_url;

    let options_: any = {
        method: "get",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json"
        })
    };

    return this.http.request(url_, options_).pipe(
        map((response_: any) => { return this.test(response_); })),
        catchError((err: any, caught: Observable<MyResponseClass | null>) => {
            if (caught instanceof Response) {
                try {
                    return this.test(<any>caught);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <MyResponseClass | null><any>Observable.throw(e);
                }
            } else
            return <MyResponseClass | null><any>Observable.throw(caught);
        })
    );
}
```

I'm still getting this error:

[image]

Here is a text version of this error:

```
Argument of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<MyResponseClass>) => MyResponseClass | Observable<MyResponseClass>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<MyResponseClass>) => ObservableInput<MyResponseClass>'.
  Type 'MyResponseClass | Observable<MyResponseClass>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<MyResponseClass>'.
    Type 'MyResponseClass' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<MyResponseClass>'.
      Type 'MyResponseClass' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<MyResponseClass>'.
        Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'MyResponseClass'.
```

What I'm doing wrong? Will you help me?

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438854/how-to-change-httpclient-code-after-update-app-to-angular-7) is the previous step which I did before that error. Maybe did I something wrong on previous step?

---

I made a changes after read all of comments so now the get() function looks like that:

```
return this.http.request(url_, options_).pipe(
            map((response_: any) => { return this.test(response_); }),
            catchError((err: any, caught: Observable<MyResponseClass | null>) => {
                if (caught instanceof Response) {
                    try {
                        return this.test(<any>caught);
                    } catch (e) {
                        return throwError(e);
                    }
                } else
                    return throwError(caught);
            })
        );
```

and I'm still getting error:

[image]

Comment: Try using `Observable.of` instead of static `of` in your test function.

Comment: @Chris Tapay Observable.of is deprecated in rxjs@6.3.3

Comment: @Chris Tapay Here you are some details: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: Why do you use type assertion so often? I think `<MyResponseClass | null><any>Observable.throw(e)` could just be `throwError(e)` and `of<MyResponseClass | null>(<any>null)` could just be `of(null)`.

Comment: @fridoo in ...\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.d.ts you can read that 'throw' is 'static throw: typeof throwError;' so it doesn't matter if I'm using Observable.throw() or throwError()

Comment: @fridoo I modified my test function because this function will return something else than null... sometimes... but body of this function is doesn't matter on this bug.

Comment: In the line `map((response_: any) => { return this.test(response_); })),` remove the last `)`

Comment: I removed redundant ')' and refreshed image with error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed you're returning an Observable from the `test` function, when you probably shouldn't.

**Errors free example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zimn8f

Check and let me know.

Comment: change your test funtion to protected test(response: Response): Observable<MyResponseClass | null> {
      let result200: any = 'some value';
      return of<MyResponseClass | null>(result200);
  }

this same result of that.

Comment: @Presto Did you change `return of(this.test(<any>caught));` to `return this.test(<any>caught);` when you changed the `test` function? Otherwise you have an `of` in the `test` function and another one in front of the `test` function.

Comment: I was trying it after read of your comment. Doesn't affect to error.

Comment: Do you really need to return an Observable from `test`? Please remember that the caught is actually the source Observable (Http), hence its type is Observable<T>, where T is MyResponseClass, but you're providing Observable<MyResponseClass>. You can see it in the error and dirty fix it by changing `caught: Observable<MyResponseClass | null>` to `caught: Observable<any>`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't import observable from `rxjs-compat`, use `rxjs`

The only good reason to use `rxjs-compat` is if you have dependencies that still rely on an older version of `rxjs`.

Comment: ok, I uninstalled this package and back to import Observable from 'rxjs'. I've got still this same error. It is not a solution.